# Python List - rows and columns

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have the following code;

```
for d in range(0,len(newlist),4):
    codewordgrid.append(list(codedmessage[d:d+6]))
```

This then prints something along the lines of this;

```
<<<CODEWORD GRID>>>
[['E', 'A'], ['E', 'A'], ['E', 'A'], ['F', 'C'], ['F', 'C'], ['F', 'C']]
[['F', 'C'], ['F', 'C'], ['F', 'A'], ['F', 'A'], ['F', 'A'], ['C', 'A']]
[['F', 'A'], ['C', 'A'], ['C', 'A'], ['C', 'A']]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Basically my aim is this - to print the list in an unlimited number of rows (so basically the message can be any length in rows), but to limit the number of columns to 4. So I would like the example to look more like this;

```
    ['E', 'A'], ['E', 'A'], ['E', 'A'], ['F', 'C']
    ['F', 'C'], ['F', 'C'], ['F', 'C'], ['F', 'C']
    ['F', 'A'], ['F', 'A'], ['F', 'A'], ['C', 'A']
    ['F', 'A'], ['C', 'A'], ['C', 'A'], ['C', 'A']
```

So just to reiterate, depending on how long the codedmessage is depends on the amount of rows, however I would like to limit the number of columns to 4 and I am unsure how to do this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show `codewordgrid`?

Comment: He did.  Its first three elements are lists of two-element lists, its remaining element are empty lists.

Comment: I declared it as such, `codewordgrid = []`

Comment: Just change `[d:d+6]` to `[d:d+4]`? Also note that you use different lists in the range and to get the items from. Seems like a copy-paste error to me.

Comment: Actually its not codewordgrid you will have to show, but code message it self. :)

Comment: So, did any of the below answers help you? If so, it would be awfully nice if you could accept or upvote some of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the list with itertools:

```
chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable(your_nested_list):
for i in range(0, len(chain), 4):
   print str(chain[i:i+4])[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a copy-paste error here, as you just have to change the `6` to `4` when you do the slice. Also note that you use two different lists for the `range` and for the slice. I think you meant this:

```
for d in range(0,len(codedmessage),4):
    codewordgrid.append(list(codedmessage[d:d+4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without `itertools` or other modules:

```
def eachToken(codewordgrid):
  for element in codewordgrid:
    for token in element:
      yield token

for i, token in enumerate(eachToken(codewordgrid)):
  print token, ("," if i % 4 else "\n"),
print
```

Comment: isn't `i` the first element of each `token` and `token` the other of each two element list? for example: the first yield unpacks to `i='E'` and `token='A'`...

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to wrap that in `enumerate()`.  I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy should be able to handle this pretty easily. If codedmessage is a list:

```
import numpy
codewordgrid = numpy.array(codedmessage).reshape(-1,4,2)
numpy.savetxt('codewordgrid.txt',codewordgrid,fmt='%s',delimiter=", ")
```

The only difference here is that there won't be a comma between codeword pairs.

e.g.

```
['E' 'A'], ['E' 'A'], ['E' 'A'], ['F' 'C']
['F' 'C'], ['F' 'C'], ['F' 'C'], ['F' 'C']
['F' 'A'], ['F' 'A'], ['F' 'A'], ['C' 'A']
['F' 'A'], ['C' 'A'], ['C' 'A'], ['C' 'A']
```

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k! I've updated my answer so that it should give the desired output.